# EXCEPT. Показать дубликаты тоже

Tags: sql-server, sql

Есть две таблицы:

[image]

Необходимо из первой таблицы показать записи, значение столбца "Код" которых не совпадает со значениями из столбца "Код" второй таблицы:
Делаю так:

```
SELECT Код FROM Table1
EXCEPT
SELECT Код FROM Table2
```

Ответ:

```
1
2
5
6
```

Обратите внимание что запись с кодом **2** показана только один раз, хотя в Table 1 она встречается дважды. Как мне отобразить **дублирующие** значения тоже? Хочу чтобы ответ выглядел так:

```
1
2
2
5
6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * from table1 where Код NOT in (SELECT Код FROM Table2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from table1 where Код in (SELECT Код FROM Table1
EXCEPT
SELECT Код FROM Table2)
```